# scan_iter results of redis python is returning different results than DBSIZE

Tags: python, redis, redis-cluster

I would like to get some statistics from redis-cluster like number of keys, hashes and count of all inner field keys using python client.

but when I run every time it is giving different results. I can assure there is no background process that is setting or deleting any keys or hashes or inner fields of hashes etc.

I've below python code -

```
import redis

redisObj = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis-12345.c1.us-west-2-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com', port=18933, db=0, decode_responses=False, ssl=True, password='<mypassword>', ssl_ca_certs= '../redis_ca.pem')

keys = 0
hashKeys = 0
innerHashes = 0
counter = 0
batch_counter = 0
for key in redisObj.scan_iter('*'):
    if key != None:
        counter += 1
        valType = redisObj.type(key).decode('utf-8')
        match valType:
            case "string":
                keys +=  1
            case "hash":
                hashKeys += 1
                valDict = redisObj.hgetall(key)
                for i in valDict.items():
                    innerHashes += 1
            case _:
                continue

print("keys: "  + str(keys))
print("hashKeys:    " + str(hashKeys))
print("innerHashes: " + str(innerHashes))
```

This code during every execution returns different results like -

```
$ ./venv/bin/python3 redis-load-stats-stg2.py
keys: 0
hashKeys:    2819
innerHashes: 19220
$ ./venv/bin/python3 redis-load-stats-stg2.py
keys: 0
hashKeys:    1102
innerHashes: 12185
$ ./venv/bin/python3 redis-load-stats-stg2.py
keys: 0
hashKeys:    669
innerHashes: 9591
```

When I run `DBSIZE` in redis-cli get 10623 as result. This is consistent.

Why my script is returning different results than DBSIZE?

Comment: If you’re using OSS cluster, I think you have to connect to it with the cluster version of the client (redis.RedisCluster). Might be related